# How to use label.new() function in a Pane?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I use labels very well in overlayed indicators but now I'm stuck when trying to use it in a Pane (in a basic v5 MACD code I customized).

```
label.new(hist[0] < hist[1] and hist[2] < hist[1] and ShowLabels ? bar_index : na, high, color=#FF0000, text="S", textcolor=color.white, tooltip = "MACD Sell", style=label.style_label_down)
```

It returns with the following error message:

```
The 'timeframe' argument is incompatible with functions that have side effects
```

I have a suspicion that `bar_index` and/or `high` is problematic but didn't find how to make `label.new()` functions Pane-compliant.

Answer (score 1):

It's the `label.new()` function that causes the issue.

The `timeframe` argument of the `indicator()` is there to provide a quick and easy way to do MTF. When you get this error, it means that calculating your script for the other timeframes simply failed.

This will happen when you have drawings as they are not so easy to calculate on other tiemframes.

Even the followings will trigger this error:

```
label.new(na, na, na)
line.new(na, na, na, na)
box.new(na, na, na, na)
```

The workaround is, simply remove the `timeframe` argument from your `indicator()` and use the `security()` function to calculate the values you need from the other timeframes. And then use those values in your drawing function calls.

Comment: Hm, and how to tell the label.new() to be displayed only on a certain timeframe? In the overlayed indicators, the same syntax works well, the label is displayed only if resInMinutes == 60, in this case. I see that I can "request the security" from 1H but I do it in every timeframe viewed, not only on 1H.